# How to group dates in adjacent cells together to create a range?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of cells containing dates. Some of the dates are sequential (eg. Sept 2, Sept 3, Sept 4), while some are standalone. I was hoping to store all the dates in one cell, where the sequential dates would be stored as a range, and all the standalone dates and ranges separated by a comma  (eg. "Sept 2", "Sept 3", "Sept 4", "Sept 8" would be stored as "Sept 2-4, Sept 8" instead).

Is there a way to do this with an Excel formula?

Here's how the data looks currently:

[image: Excel Snapshot]

And here's the intended outcome:

[image: Excel Snapshot 2]

I've taken multiple cracks at this, but the closest I got was creating a list of all sequential dates.

Comment: A formula is not the correct method for this.  This would be better suited for vba.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way at all with normal formulas. You'll need to code something in VBA for sure. Actually you tagged the question with VBA so please, post the code you've tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting.

Comment: The edit queue is currently full so I can't provide minor edits, but I think this is a good question that deserves a look at reopening. It gives a clear problem, short sample data, and expected results, so to me at least, I don't see missing details that would help add clarity to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way, but below is one way you can do this with a formula if you have the newest version of Excel. I assume your ranges runs from column B to Column L and starts in the second row. Note it is sensitive to formatting, so make sure that is consistent. Also note that it works for ranges that eclipse months, but not years.

```
=LET(v, TEXTJOIN(",",, TEXT(B2:L2, "m/d/yyyy")),
w, SUBSTITUTE(v, "1/0/1900,", "!"),
x, IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(w, "!", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),""),
y, IF(RIGHT(x,1)=",", LEFT(x,LEN(x)-1), x),
z, LEN(y),
a, IF(z<11, y, LEFT(y, SEARCH(",",y)-1)&"-"&RIGHT(RIGHT(y,12), 12-SEARCH(",", RIGHT(y,12)))),
b, TEXT(MONTH(LEFT(a, SEARCH("-", a)-1))*29, "mmm")&" "&DAY(LEFT(a, SEARCH("-", a)-1)),
c, TEXT(MONTH(RIGHT(a, LEN(a)-SEARCH("-", a)))*29, "mmm")&" "&DAY(RIGHT(a, LEN(a)-SEARCH("-", a))),
d, IFERROR(IF(LEN(a)<11, TEXT(MONTH(a)*29, "mmm")&" "&DAY(a),
IF(LEFT(b,3)=LEFT(c,3), b&"-"&RIGHT(c, LEN(c)-4), b&"-"&c)),""),
TEXTJOIN(",  ",1,d))
```

For example:
[image]